# How to create a line chart with altering colors?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtcharts, pyqtchart

How can I create in Qt a line chart with changing colors? Something like this:

[image]

I can only see a way to change the color of the entire chart.

EDIT:
The option of creating a few series is no good for me, since my series are dynamic, and the points are moving constantly.

I'd much rather it be 1 series with a lot of points, like I have it now.

Comment: What library are you using: pyqtchart, pyqtgraph, etc?

Comment: Plain PyQt5.QtChart